# Problem building project with Google Analytics lib in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

My project is a `universal iPhone/iPad` app and it was all working fine in the previous version of XCode. I just upgraded and now when I try to build for the device (it works in the simulator), I get this build error:

> Google Analytics SDK/Library/libGoogleAnalytics.a, file is universal but does not contain a(n) armv7 slice for architecture armv7"

I am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help.

Comment: of course it will work on the simulator because it will use the `.a` version `i386` but iPad device using `armv7`architecture, please make sure your using the correct version because you upgraded to iOS 4.3

Comment: visit Google Analytics SDK and download their latest version of the SDK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to download the latest Google Analytics iPhone SDK you might have an old version which is not compatible with the iOS 4.3

[latest Google Analytics iPhone SDK](http://dl.google.com/gaformobileapps/GoogleAnalyticsiOS_1.5.1.tar.gz)

Comment: I was sure I had the latest version so didn't try that, but that fixed it. Many thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I updated your link form version 1.1 to 1.5

Answer (score 4):

Please try the following, This is a first aid only. You can build it with out any errors untill you find the latest verison of library that supports armv7.

Take the build settings and set the value for key `Build Active Architecture Only` to `Yes`.

[image]

Let get one thing straight. This is a temporary fix only. You have to update your library.
Hope this helps somebody.

**Extra** : You can download the latest google analytics library which supports armv7 and armv7s from [here](http://dl.google.com/gaformobileapps/GoogleAnalyticsiOS_1.5.1.tar.gz).

Answer (score 0):

You must use the latest GA SDK version for iOS. You can find it here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/resources

(The other answer didn't work for me).